# Dwarf Fortress Character and Graphics Sets

Tags: dwarf-fortress

What are clear, intuitive tile sets that help beginning players understand what all is on the map?

Tiles are spread across two different sets: character sets are the ASCII and graphics sets are the creatures.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because Arqade does not support asset/modification recommendations, or location.

Comment: @FEIchinger There is no blanket ban on mod recommendations anymore as per the [meta] post, [Is “mod rec” really an umbrella category that we want to use? Or is it confusing the situation?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/6828/4797)

Comment: @galacticninja I see nothing in here about it being a mod recommendation.  This is an entirely subjective question.

Comment: You may want to try the noob pack. Has a texture pack as well as other helpful features to start with.

Comment: @Frank That was a reply to FEIchinger's potentially misleading comment, specifically: "*...Arqade does not support ...modification recommendations...*" Also, I disagree with the view that this question is entirely subjective. OP's problem is that he's looking for "*clear, intuitive tile sets that help beginning players understand what all is on the map*", so answers will most likely be graphic mods/sets. From the [meta post I linked to](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/6828/4797): "*Recommending solutions from a large number of possibilities is the core of a wide swath of questions.*"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Phoebus' Graphic Set](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=57557.0) comes both packaged with DF and separate.

[image]
**Legend**
[image]

Comment: I'm actually thinking of switching to this, just for the materials icons.  It makes it really easy to see iron, lignite, etc, etc.

Answer (score 13):

Mike Mayday's [graphical character set](http://mayday.w.staszic.waw.pl/df.php) is one of the more popular sets, including both characters and tiles.

[image: Example of the pack]

One benefit is that he ships a zip of DF already set up with his graphics package.

It is available from his website [here](http://mayday.w.staszic.waw.pl/df.php).

Answer (score 6):

I'm not using it at the moment, but [Ironhand's Graphics Set](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=53180.0) looks gorgeous!

[image: Tileset]

[image: Dwarves]

I couldn't find any good shots of it in action, though…