# My dwarves are sleeping in each other's beds!

Tags: dwarf-fortress

At least for the first few waves of migration, I try to make sure every dwarf has his or her own bedroom. So each one gets a small room with a bed in it assigned to him or her. But the dwarves don't seem to take any notice of this: they all just sleep in whichever room they feel like!

Now, if this doesn't bother the owner of the room (I don't know whether it does) then I might as well just leave all the rooms unassigned and let the dwarves sleep wherever (this would save me a lot of room-assigning whenever a big wave arrives) and I probably wouldn't need as many rooms, since not everybody wants to sleep at the same time.

Is there a way I can force the dwarves to sleep only in their designated room or in the overspill/new migrant dormitory?

Comment: @Grace, both versions of the word are actually accepted (I checked the other day)

Comment: @Juan - Apparently it depends on the dictionary, the one I checked before had only dwarves as a plural. (I made the initial correction)

Comment: @Juan It's not a matter of which version is accepted. [It's a matter that if you're going to edit the post for a replacement, then it should hit all instances and not just most](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2252/what-changes-are-required-to-create-my-own-dwarf-fortress-graphics "Guess who started the whole not-catching-all-instances?"). And curse your counter-counter-counter-counter, Arda!

Comment: ah, I didn't understand the previous edits were the reason you changed it, sorry.

Comment: Is it standard practice to edit out phrases that add character like "wherever they damn well feel like"? That seems a shame.

Comment: I'd be very interested to see this whole question answered. Say you have every dwarf assigned to a bed. Why do they still sleep in beds assigned to other dwarves? How can you stop this? It annoys my OCD incredibly. :)

Comment: @Seamus - I've seen a question flagged as offensive for less. I was trying to be pre-emptive. Seeing as it's still your question you can always revert it, I have a 1RR. :-)

Comment: 1 dorf, 2 dorfs. All DF players will know what you're talking about :-)

Comment: Yeah, "dorves" just looks wrong...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dwarves will generally sleep wherever they see fit unless they have an assigned bed, in which case they will prefer this one. Sleeping in an assigned bed does give happy thoughts, being unable to makes a dwarf unhappy.

However, you don't generally have to bother with assigning beds since dwarves will claim unassigned bedrooms for themselves automatically.

Just a side-note: married dwarves and children share beds.

Comment: The main reason you give dwarfs beds is so the they can have some possessions. I use the bedroom as an anchor for their cabinets and coffers so they can store items that they claim.

Comment: "Just a side-note: married dwarves and children share beds." What sort of inhumane creatures are these, to **share beds**?! How deplorable.

Comment: @Doltknuckle - it's actually mostly to stop the bad thoughts dwarves get from sleeping without their own bed.

Comment: @Mana. Of course they're inHUMANe. They're DWARVES.

Comment: @WillfulWizard: Some irony was intended in my comment. :P

Answer (score 10):

There's also [a bug](http://www.bay12games.com/dwarves/mantisbt/view.php?id=34) causing dwarves to not respect assigned beds when choosing where to sleep. Generally it doesn't make a huge difference, but when you get nobles showing up (who have preferences about how fancy their bedrooms need to be), they can become unhappy about sleeping in an inferior room, even though they chose to sleep there.

Edit: per the changelog, this bug has now been fixed for the next release. You may have to remove old beds and make new ones though, as there were some issues that weren't fixable by just having the new version update the save.