# A good UI for Dwarf Fortress

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Do you know if there exist a fancier user interface for Dwarf Fortress instead of the ASCII one?

Comment: Related (if not duplicate): http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/dwarf-fortress-character-and-graphics-sets

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only official dwarf fortress is the ASCII you know and love (or hate!). You've got several options, however:

-Download a [graphics pack mod](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=57557.0), turning all the ascii characters into small images instead.

-External utilities like [Dwarf Therapist](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=66525.0) can make assigning jobs much easier.

-Download an external viewer, like [Stonesense](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=43260.0), to view your dwarf fortress in "glorious" isometric 3d.

Answer (score 9):

I'd suggest the [Lazy Newb pack](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=59026.0) as a great place to start. It includes several different tile sets, as well as many useful utilities (like Dwarf Therapist and more).